# How to display different image depends on td value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress and would like to build a page with shipment trackin similar function.

i.e. if a package is delivered and that delivery result cell is not empty, then show colored image, otherwise show grey image.

my delivery result cell has the id "f1" and is empty

```
<td id="f1"><td>
```

After that i tried following code without success

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById ( "f1" );
if (x == null){
document.write('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/airplane_off.png" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; margin: 1px;" />');
}
else{
document.write('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/airplane_on.png" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; margin: 1px;" />');
}
</script>
```

Your help is appreciated

Comment: My English is quite poor so I'll post the URL for better understanding.
<https://kaige.de/sia/501-00000000/> This one does have data in Flight Departure Date (line 130) and therefore the image should be colored(airplane_on.png)
<https://kaige.de/sia/501-00000001/> This one has no data  in Flight Departure Date and therefore the image should be grey (airplane_off.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to see if the inner html is empty.

You should be able to tell if the content is blank using `innerHTML`:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("f1");

if (x && x.innerHTML.trim() == ""){
  document.write('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/airplane_off.png" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; margin: 1px;" />');
}
else{
  document.write('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/airplane_on.png" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; margin: 1px;" />');
}
```

Note that your example uses `<td id="f1"><td>`. The tag is not being closed, which will cause issues if you have that in the page too.

The other thing to note is that `td` needs to be in a proper table structure (meaning inside a `tr` which needs to be inside a `table`) otherwise you won't be able to target it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, second <td> tag is is closed and they are in a table. your codes works only half because it always shows the "else" case. it seems the cell is never empty even the source code has nothing between the <td> tag.
I've posted the URLs in my question, could you please have a look into that?

Comment: updated answer to include `trim()` if that's not working there may be something else in there, and you might want to `console.log(x.innerHTML)`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is almost correct. Try giving innerHTML after `getElementById()`

```
var data = document.getElementById ( "f1" );
if (x.innerHTML === ''){
  document.write('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/airplane_off.png" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; margin: 1px;" />');
}
else{
  document.write('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/airplane_on.png" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; margin: 1px;" />');
}
```

Comment: i doesn't work because of x.innerHTML, Chrome reports an error <Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null>

Comment: @KaiChen please make sure that, the particular html tag has been rendered by the browser before this code was executed

Comment: try doing a console.log('data ',document.getElementById ( "f1" ))